# Reference file in jar with plain Java File

Tags: java, eclipse, sphinx4

I'm trying to create a plain `Main.java` file with 2 jar dependencies. I have the program up and running in an Eclipse Java project but when running from command-line as a single java file it can't find a resource path.

The problematic code:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();


conf.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us");
conf.setDictionaryPath("custom.dic");
conf.setLanguageModelPath("custom.lm");
```

Now the `/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us` is part of the `sphinx4-data.jar`. This path just can't be found when I'm running this as a plain Java file on my Raspberry Pi.

Compile:

`javac -cp ".:/home/ivaro18/sphinx4-core.jar:/home/ivaro18/sphinx4-data.jar" Main.java`

Run:

`java -cp ".:/home/ivaro18/sphinx4-core.jar:/home/ivaro18/sphinx4-data.jar" Main`

But the error returned:

> Can't locate resouce:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us

This worked perfectly in Eclipse Java project, having added these 2 jars to my classpath. But when I'm running this as a plain Java file on my pi, it can't find the resource.

Comment: /edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us, is this a directory with respect to your current directory that stores some file?

Comment: /edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us is a directory in sphinx4-data.jar, but I guess it might also exist on the filesytem if the JAR is processed in Eclipse. The token `resource:` hints that a search will be made on the classpath, or something of that nature, but the documentation doesn't seem to say exactly how. I wonder if it would help to unpack the CMU JARs into the same directory, add the application class(es) and then repack the whole thing to make one big JAR?

Comment: Most likely the jars are simply under different path or named differently.